# In a c# UWP app, when the code hits the await key word, the error message 'value does not fall in the expected range'

Tags: c#, winui-3

I am using Template Studio for WinUI targeting .NET 7. When the code hits the await keyword in async Task<>program definition, it throws a "Value not in expected range" error on `await SqlConnection.OpenAsync();` and on `await cmd.ExecuteReaderAsync();`

When I use the Async in a console app (.NET 7.0), it works.

SQL Express 2019 is the database. Using the same connection string, database and table in both cases.

Console code that works in the console app targeting NET 7.0:

```
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace ConsoleAsync 
{
    class Program {
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            var cnStr = @"Data Source=.\SQLExpress;Initial Catalog=Company;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True";
            using var cn = new SqlConnection(cnStr);
            {
                await cn.OpenAsync();
                Console.WriteLine("Connected to SQL Express 20219");

                const string query = "select * from Star";

                using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(query, cn))
                using (var reader = await cmd.ExecuteReaderAsync())
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        int id = (int)reader["Id"];
                        string name = (string)reader["Name"];
                        Console.WriteLine($"{id}: {name}");
                    }
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine("End");
        }
    }
```

Code that fails on the first `await` in the Template Studio targeting NET 7.0 {"Value does not fall within the expected range."}:

```
public partial class AsyncViewModel : ObservableRecipient
{
    public AsyncViewModel()
    {
    }

    public async Task<ObservableCollection<Star>> GetAllStarsAsync()
    {
        var stars = new ObservableCollection<Star>();

        var cnStr = @"Data Source=.\SQLExpress;Initial Catalog=Company;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True";
        const string query = "select * from Star";

        using var cn = new SqlConnection(cnStr);
        {
            await cn.OpenAsync();
            using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(query, cn))
            using (var reader = await cmd.ExecuteReaderAsync())
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    int id = (int)reader["Id"];
                    string name = (string)reader["Name"];
                    Console.WriteLine($"{id}: {name}");
                }
            }
        }

        return stars;

    }
}
```

The table created in the Company database:

```
create table Star(
    Id int not null primary key identity(1, 1),
    Name nvarchar(50) not null
  );
 
  insert into Star(Name) values
      ('Aldebaran'),
      ('Sirius'),
      ('Betelgeuse');
}
```

Call Stack:

```
System.ArgumentException
  HResult=0x80070057
  Message=Value does not fall within the expected range.
  Source=WinRT.Runtime
  StackTrace:
   at WinRT.ExceptionHelpers.<ThrowExceptionForHR>g__Throw|20_0(Int32 hr)
   at WinRT.ExceptionHelpers.ThrowExceptionForHR(Int32 hr)
   at ABI.Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls.IItemsControlMethods.set_ItemsSource(IObjectReference _obj, Object value)
   at Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls.ItemsControl.set_ItemsSource(Object value)
   at WinUI3BasicApp.Views.MainPage..ctor() in C:\aWorkspace\aWinUI\SqlConnections\WinUI3BasicApp\WinUI3BasicApp\Views\MainPage.xaml.cs:line 23
```

If I comment out this line of code `InventoryList.ItemsSource = result;` in the MainPage.xaml.cs then the function will fill the observable collect star. The InventoryList is the ListView name for the data source.

Does anyone have any suggestions how how to fix this issue?

Edit: Using WinUI 3 Basic App Project Template
Target Net 7
Model:

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace WinUI3Sql.Models {
    public class Star {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

ViewModel code:

```
using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.ComponentModel;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using WinUI3Sql.Models;

namespace WinUI3Sql.ViewModels {
    public partial class MainPageViewModel : ObservableObject {
        public MainPageViewModel() { }

        public async Task<IEnumerable<Star>> GetAllStarsAsync()
        {
            var stars = new ObservableCollection<Star>();

            var cnStr = @"Data Source=.\SQLExpress;Initial Catalog=Company;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True";
            const string query = "select * from Star";

            using var cn = new SqlConnection(cnStr);
            {
                cn.Open();
                using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(query, cn))
                {
                    var reader = await cmd.ExecuteReaderAsync();
                    {
                        while (reader.Read())
                        {
                            var star = new Star();
                            star.Id = (int)reader["Id"];
                            star.Name = (string)reader["Name"];
                            stars.Add(star);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            return stars;
        }
    }
}
```

MainPage.xaml.code:

```
using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using WinUI3Sql.Models;
using WinUI3Sql.ViewModels;

namespace WinUI3Sql.Views {
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page {
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            ViewModel = Ioc.Default.GetRequiredService<MainPageViewModel>();

            ObservableCollection<Star> x = new ObservableCollection<Star>();
            x = (ObservableCollection<Star>)ViewModel.GetAllStarsAsync().Result;
            InventoryList.ItemsSource = x;
        }
        public MainPageViewModel ViewModel { get; }
    }
}
```

The code hangs now when the await line is run.
Using a Postgres database, the above code works when making the changes to the connection string and using Npgsql. For the Postgres, the `await cn.OpenAsync();` hung. But when the await / Async connection was removed, the `var reader = await cmd.ExecuteReaderAsync();` worked and the data was displayed.

Comment: Please provide more information to help us further check the problem for you. What the SQL API are you using? Did you refer to any documentation? Could you please provide a [mcve]?

Comment: Points to check - actual database location and security parameters. You've also got a mix of old and new `using` syntax - not sure whether semicolon and brackets will cause issues.

Comment: Please show the *complete* stack trace instead of just the error message.